# Changing background doesn't work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser

I have a script that changes my background image every few seconds. It works for me, however, some users reported that it's not working on Safari browsers.
I am using Chrome and it works great, but some of them also have problems on Google Chrome. Any ideas what might cause this problem?

```
    changeBackground();

    function changeBackground(){
        var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/woman.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")');

            }

            changeBackground();

        }, 6000);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to alert the value of currentBackground variable on safari?

Comment: You don't need to check with full path: Just do like this: `if(currentBackground == 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")'){`

Comment: How can you call function inside that?

Comment: How large are the images? It may be that they are still being downloaded when the next image comes in. You may need to use a preloader, or slow down the timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a first default background image, probably in safari can't get the CSS url image for the first match:

```
changeBackground();

    function changeBackground(){
        var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/woman.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://example.com/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")');

            // ADD THIS ELSE
            } else {
                  // SET THE FIRST AND DEFAUT BACKGROUND
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")')
                currentBackground = 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")';
            }

            changeBackground();

        }, 6000);
    }
```

[The JSFiddle tried in safari for windows.](https://jsfiddle.net/L87d9fx4/)

**UPDATE**

Or you can use a safer way, use a counter instead of the css style like this:

```
changeBackground();

var currentBackground = 0;

function changeBackground(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(currentBackground);
    if (currentBackground == 0){
      currentBackground = 1;
      $("body").css("background-image", 'url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/7125/water-trees-lake.jpg")');
    }
    else if(currentBackground == 1){
      currentBackground = 2;
      $("body").css("background-image", 'url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/4243/black-and-white-forest-trees-branches.jpg")');
    }
    else if(currentBackground == 2){
      currentBackground = 0;  
      $("body").css("background-image", 'url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/9159/pexels-photo.jpg")');
    } 

    changeBackground();

  }, 6000);
}
```

[The JSFiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/L87d9fx4/2/)

Comment: Updated answer is great. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `url` standards

use relative url instead:

```
 changeBackground();

    function changeBackground(){
        var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentBackground == 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd2.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")');

            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("/images/new-home-page/slajd3.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")');

            }

            changeBackground();

        }, 6000);
    }
```